# Where can I find a pre-populated json file for testing?

Tags: json, testing

I am building an application that can import JSON data, I want to test about 10k entries, and I don't feel like building a JSON string with that many entries.... so does anyone have a location where I could find some generic populated JSON files? (Music Albums / Movie Listings / Animal Kingdom / Census data / Car Models... I'm not horribly picky, I just need some good data to test with.)

Comment: what did you end up using and is your app online somewhere? (I'm building a JSON aggregator now and don't want to re-invent the wheel...)

Comment: @Matt So, you get the data? if yes, please share.

Comment: here: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=google

Answer (score 12):

This is a site that is in beta that can give you data in JSON, XML or CSV. All lists are customizable. This is a sample call: http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json
Documentation here: http://mysafeinfo.com/content/documentation ; See a full list under Datasets on the main menu

Comment: That's really quite a horrible site to test with, seeing as it sends the response with a `Content-Type` of `text/plain`. Use something like the SE API (e.g. http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow), which correctly sends `application/json`.

Comment: Lol, I get XML from that site, that doesnt work at all

Answer (score 1):

[Vienna's Open Data website](http://data.wien.gv.at/katalog/baumkataster.html) provide various databases. For example, their [Tree register](http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien:BAUMOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json)

**Edit:**

The old link is dead.  A great place to find test data is Socrata which aggregates government data.  There's plenty of data to test with:

https://dev.socrata.com/data/

If you look through the catalogs, there's usually a JSON export option.  [Here's an example](https://data.nationalservice.gov/api/views/INLINE/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD) from the National Service for Age Group and volunteering.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead :(

Answer (score 1):

There are few websites that have raw data that can be customized to a JSON format. Here is a link for some raw data information [Data](http://www.geonames.org/data-sources.html)